# Multiple Angularfire pull requests failing

Tags: angularfire

So I need to be able to pull multiple items one after another, and for whatever reason, the second ".on" never executes. I have a console.log in there that never gets printed.

The code goes as follows

```
 var ref = new Firebase(url1);
ref.once("value", function(data) {    
    $scope.userList = data.val();
    var userArray = [];
    angular.forEach($scope.userList, function(value, key) {
        userArray.push(value);
    });
    $scope.searchName = userArray[0];
    var request = new Firebase(reqUrl);
    console.log($scope.searchName);
    request.set($scope.searchName);
    var ref2 = new Firebase(url);
    ref2.once("value", function(data) {
        console.log("enter");
        $scope.infoList = data.val();
        var infoArray = [];
        angular.forEach($scope.infoList, function(value, key) {
            infoArray.push(value);
        });
        $scope.params = infoArray;
        console.log($scope.params);
    });
});
```

Why would the second .once fail? Enter is never being printed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workaround. Using

```
$scope.returnedObj = $firebaseObject(ref);
    $scope.returnedObj.$loaded().then(function () {...})
```